# Disabling a website's default hotkeys using Jquery on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

So on a website, clicking certain buttons(ie: left or right arrow buttons) does an action. I'm programming a chrome extension, and I need to disable those buttons and replace them with my own shortcuts. How do I do this using javascript/jQuery?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add DOM event handlers to your document.

For example: This will override left and right arrow buttons as you asked

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function keydown(evt) {


    switch (evt.keyCode) {
      case 37: // Left arrow
               alert("Left arrow Pressed");
               break;
      case 39: // Right arrow
               alert("Right arrow Pressed");
               break;
     }
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3SHU/1/)

For keyboard shortcuts involving 'ctrl' the following example will help. 
This will override ctrl + f (shortcut for 'find')

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function keydown(evt) {
  var cmd = (evt.ctrlKey ? 1 : 0);
  if (cmd === 1) {// To check whether control is selected or not.

    switch (evt.keyCode) {
      case 70: // f
        alert("hi");
            break;}
  }
});
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v3SHU/)